# FaceBook Like away

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have a page , with hide content , the content appear when a user click on facebook button like ,

the url that user click on like is variable , it's not one url ,

how can i know if the user liked this url before ? to show him the content

my language is php and html

and i use this code to relode the page after the visitor like on the url

```
FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create", function(href) {
                var data = { action: "virallocker", myID: "'.$my_id.'"};
                jQuery.post("viral.php", data, function(response) {
                    if (virallocker_use) location.reload();
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldnt be looking for the user to click on the button to show the content. What if the user has already liked your page before? Should he be hitting the unlike button to get the content?

Instead you can query the userlikes with FQL or opengraph and see if your page/url is liked by the user and then show him the content.

**Refer to :** 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/